# ActionSheet causing mutliple UIPopovers to show on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-universal-app

I have a universal app and have an action sheet with a few buttons. When I tap the add button (navigationItem.right) I want it to show in a popoever. It does this correctly, however, with the actionSheet tied to the barbutton item, it allows me to continually tap the add button and have more popup.

I thought tapping outside the popover would dismiss this...

```
- (IBAction)ShowItemAdd:(id)sender
{
    addActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:[dataObj.preferences objectForKey:@"appts_name"], @"Reserve", nil];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isPad]) {
        [addActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] animated:YES];
    } else {
        [addActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Why is this not auto dismissing if I have it bound to the barbutton item?

**EDIT**

Tapping anywhere in the navigationItem bar (blue bar) at the top will not close the actionSheet, however tapping outside of the nav controller, will dismiss the actionsheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you should first check to see whether your actionsheet is already visible, and if it is, dismiss it instead of creating a new actionsheet.

```
- (IBAction)ShowItemAdd:(id)sender
{
    if ([addActionSheet isVisible]) {

        [addActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[addActionSheet cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];

    } else {

        addActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:[dataObj.preferences objectForKey:@"appts_name"], @"Reserve", nil];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isPad]) {
            [addActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] animated:YES];
        } else {
            [addActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isVisible always returns false;

Comment: Do you have a property on your viewController to store the reference to the actionSheet?  Try changing `addActionSheet` to `self.addActionSheet`

Comment: I do have addActionSheet as a property. I changed it to `self.addActionSheet` and still same thing.

Comment: I apologize I had the is visible after I was reinstantiating the addActionSheet. I moved it to the top and it works. Thanks!